# How to recover wiped out custom workspace in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am working in my local Jenkins where I used folder insider D driver from my local machine only and set it up in Jenkins job as "Use custom workspace" I wipe out data from Workspace using Jenkins and it removed data from my local machine.
Is there any way to retrieve it again

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. I wanted to keep some workspaces. After the job was done, was triggered another job which was created for backup, which sent data to another server and the workspace was cleaned from the Jenkins server.

I was never able to recover deleted data by Jenkins so I made this workaround.

If you are interested in this solution
I'll look for those pipelines after my vacation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).